# How to get local min in a list?

Tags: python, list

Can anyone suggest a method to get local min in a list?

For example, I have a list `[50, 50, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 49, 49, 49, 48, 48, 48, 47, 47, 48, 48, 13, 12, 11, 10, 11, 12]`.

I want to get the answer `[49, 47, 10]`, and the index.

I had tried, but I get the answer like `[49, 50, 47, 48, 10, 11, 12]`.

Can someone help me to revise the code?

Thanks a lot.

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    if (i != 0) & (i+1 != len(list)):
        if (list[i] == list[i + 1]):
            repeat += 1
        elif (list[i] < list[i - 1]):
            repeat = 1
            continue
        elif (list[i] < list[i + 1]):
            group_list.append(list[i])
```

Comment: I would first remove the duplicates. Then go on to pick all the numbers that satisfy the condition `list[i] < list[i-1] and list[i] < list[i+1]`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my situation the duplicates appear frequently. So I need to take condition into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Please avoid using `list` as a name for your list. `list` is a predefined keyword in Python. You can use `or` to check if you are at the beginning or end of the list and at the same time compare values to their left and right. Assuming your list name is `l`, I think you want this:

```
mins = [x for i,x in enumerate(l) if ((i==0) or (l[i-1]>=x)) and ((i==len(l)-1) or (x<l[i+1]))]
```

output:

```
[49, 47, 10]
```

Comment: you can always use for loop if the list compression are getting too messy.

Comment: @VishalSingh I think _too messy_ is subjective. I find this list comprehension perfectly readable while you might disagree :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and yours advice.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the list and find places where it changes from decreasing to increasing.

```py
def local_minima(lst):
    mins = []
    decreasing = True
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        a = lst[i]
        b = lst[i + 1]
        if not decreasing and b < a:
            decreasing = True
        elif decreasing and b > a:
            mins.append(a)
            decreasing = False
    return mins
```

```py
>>> local_minima([50, 50, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 49, 49, 49, 48, 48, 48, 47, 47, 48, 48, 13, 12, 11, 10, 11, 12])
[49, 47, 10]
```

Comment: Your answer seems good, but how about local min at the boundary, say `local_minima([3,2,1])` ?

Comment: @jasonwong You could add something to check if it's still decreasing at the end pretty easily. Checking if it's increasing at the start on the other hand is harder (e.g. `local_minima([2, 2, 3])`); would require adding more code but the concept is similar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
It's work and solved my problem.